# how to use debugPrint for image.network?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-image, debug-print

I want to see the link of the image in the terminal using debugPrint.
kindly help me.
This is my code:

```
           FutureBuilder<Iterable<SubCategories>>(
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                          Image.network(
                            snapshot.data!.elementAt(index).logo,
                          ),
                    );
                }),
```

Comment: do you mean like clickable link in log console ?

Comment: @sonic like console.write in javascript

Comment: `debugPrint(snapshot.data!.elementAt(index).logo)` ?

Comment: yes right, but I didn't know that I should write below itemBuilder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try out this:**

```
**Note:** import log as **dart.developer** (import 'dart:developer';)





     FutureBuilder<Iterable<SubCategories>>(
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {                  
                        return ListView.builder(
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        log("Network image--->${snapshot.data!.elementAt(index).logo}");
                            return Image.network(
                                snapshot.data!.elementAt(index).logo,
                              ),
                          }
                        );
                    }),
```

Comment: Your log should be inside the itemBuilder

Comment: thank you so much Aamil Silawat! it is  `debugPrint("Network image--->${snapshot.data!.elementAt(index).logo}");`.
I didn't know that I should write it below item builder.
And thank you Ozan Taskiran!

Comment: @AymieChalouhy glad to help you in case you need help ask on snap:aamil_raza

Answer (score 1):

debugPrint only takes String as argument.
you can do something like this.
debugPrint('${snapshot.data!.elementAt(index).logo}');